# DropItem if parsed url contains key words (pipeline)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to build a spider for a school project where I am scraping recipes from allrecipes.com. Everything is working really well, however I seem to be unable to remove duplicate recipes where one url contains the actual recipe, and the other contains the same url with "video=true" appended.

Here is my attempt to dealing with this in pipelines.py:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log



class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

# minCal = 50

def __init__(self):
    self.urls_seen = set()

def process_vids(self, item, spider):
    video = "video=true"
    url = str(item.get('url'))
    if video in url:
        raise DropItem("Contains video")
    else:   
        return item

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    unique_id = item.get('url')
    if unique_id in self.urls_seen:
        raise DropItem("Duplicate Item found (%s)" % unique_id)
    else:
        self.urls_seen.add('url')
        return item
```

**settings.py:**

```
# Scrapy settings for dirbot project
BOT_NAME = 'dirbot'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['dirbot.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'dirbot.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'dirbot.items.Website'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'dirbot.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 300,}
```

**items.py:**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class Website(Item):

    name = Field()
    url = Field()
    description = Field()
    kcal = Field()
    carbs = Field()
    fat = Field()
    protein = Field()
    main = Field()
    sugar = Field()
    fibre = Field()
    author = Field()
    rating = Field()
    img = Field()
```

**dnot.py:**

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from dirbot.items import Website
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
import urlparse
import scrapy

page = "http://allrecipes.com/recipes/main.aspx?Page=%d#recipes"

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dnot"
    allowed_domains = ["allrecipes.com"]
    start_urls = [page % 1]

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('allrecipes.com'), restrict_xpaths = '//a[contains(.,"NEXT")]'),
    callback="parse", follow= True),
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.page_number = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        print "-------------------------------------------------"
        print self.page_number
        print "-------------------------------------------------"


        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = response.xpath('//div[@id="divGridItemWrapper"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            recipe = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/Recipe/")]/@href').extract()
            url = "http://www.allrecipes.com" 
            for nth in recipe:
                go = urlparse.urljoin(url, str(nth))
                items.append(item)
                for link in go:
                    yield Request(go, self.recipes)
        if self.page_number <= 3:
            self.page_number += 1
            yield Request(page % self.page_number)
        else:
            pass

    def recipes(self,response):
        item = Website()
        sel = Selector(response)
        recipe = response.xpath('//div[@id="content-wrapper"]')
        items = []
        print "second page - %s" % response.url

        for i in recipe:
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['description'] = i.xpath('//span[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()
            item['name'] = i.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
            item['kcal'] = i.xpath('//ul/li[contains(.,"kcal")]/span/text()').extract()
            item['carbs'] = i.xpath('//ul/li[contains(.,"Carbohydrates")]/following-sibling::li[1]//span[@id="lblNutrientValue"]/text()').extract()
            item['fat'] = i.xpath('//ul/li[contains(.,"Fat")]/following-sibling::li[1]//span[@id="lblNutrientValue"]/text()').extract()
            item['protein'] = i.xpath('//ul/li[contains(.,"Protein")]/following-sibling::li[1]//span[@id="lblNutrientValue"]/text()').extract()
            item['main'] = "allrecipes.com"
            item['sugar'] = i.xpath('//li/span[@itemprop="sugarContent"]/text()').extract()
            item['fibre'] = i.xpath('//li/span[@itemprop="proteinContent"]/text()').extract()
            item['author'] = i.xpath('//span[@id="lblUser0"]/text()').extract()
            item['rating'] = i.xpath('//div[@class="rating-stars-img"][1]/meta[1][@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content').extract()
            item['img'] = i.xpath('//img[@id="imgPhoto"]/@src').extract()
            items.append(item)
            yield item
```

I am a little new with Python, and I'm not sure if I need to convert the item['url'] into a string or not; however I have tried with the "str" and without. I have also tried a few other methods that others have used for doing something similar, but nothing has worked for me so far.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

**Example:**

item['url'] = http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Delicious-Ham-and-Potato-Soup/Detail.aspx?evt19=1&referringHubId=1
item['url'] = http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Delicious-Ham-and-Potato-Soup/Detail.aspx?evt19=1&referringHubId=1&video=true

Comment: `self.urls_seen.add(item['url'].replace("&video=true","")`

Comment: But then I have duplicate urls still? My problem is that I don't want the same recipe twice.

Comment: I presume you are putting them in a set so you won't have duplicates?

Comment: You can also do `if not item['url'].endswith("&video=true")` or `if item['url'].replace("&video=true","") not in self.urls_seen`, simplest way is just to add it, you will only have one because sets don't have duplicates presuming `&video=true` does not occur anywhere else in the string

Comment: I tried the code above and I'm still getting issues. It must be something in the way I have the settings or pipeline configured. Thanks for your help regardless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `class` that implements the `process_item` method on the `pipelines.py` file, something like:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse, parse_qs

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        url = item['url']
        u = urlparse(url)
        query = parse_qs(u.query)
        query.pop('video', None)
        u = u._replace(query=urlencode(query, True))
        unique_id = urlunparse(u)
        if unique_id and unique_id in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate Item found (%s)" % unique_id)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(unique_id)
        return item
```

Then you need to add that class, to `settings.py`

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'yourproject.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 300,
}
```

Also, your `process_vids` method isn't being used.

let me know if it helps you.

Comment: This is similar to what I have... still does not work. I feel like it must be something with how I am trying to match a string to a list or something.

Comment: I've added my entire code if you wanted to look at it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @McLean25, please check the answer again.

Comment: This works a lot better, but still not fully. It seams to remove the "video=true" link if the recipe without the video true is already present. However it won't remove the link if a similar one does not exist. This should be good enough for now though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Finally got the code to work. I edited the above answer to reflect the functional code. Thanks guys for your help!!

Comment: the best solution would be to use an extension, extensions interact with signals, so you can control the state of the requests, as you mentioned the pipeline on your question, I went with that approach, but if you want to discard the request before it becomes a duplicate, you need to use extensions.